# react-native running app on device with playstore support

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I am testing out react-native-maps. The lib requires google play service to be installed on the device.

I was able to download an image for a device with api lvl 24 ()and play service) and created an android emulator.

Problem is when I try to execute 'react-native run-android' I get an error telling me that no device is connected(while the emulator is up and running).

Another thing I noticed is that I can only start the emulator from within Android studio. The emulator cannot be used from the avd manager that was started via the command line. It shows up but all its properties are a "?" and when i check details i see this under Error:

Unknown tartget 'android-24' in C:\Users....android\avd\device.ini

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using https://www.genymotion.com/, you can use it for free, and this has support for google play services (Play Store) from the version 2.10.0.